# Use Excel VBA to open an Excel file on a LiveLink server

Tags: excel, livelink, vba

I am working on consolidating some monthly reports from different lines of business into one report for month end reporting. Currently I have to open each Excel file one at a time. This takes a while and my time could be be better used elsewhere so I decided to try to add automation to my process.

My reports are stored on a LiveLink server. Obviously the URL path does not reference the folder structure because LiveLink uses the ObjID. My data moves from folder to folder each month and I can handle that in my code. The issue I am having is I can't seem to figure out how to structure the .Open statement so that my file opens.

For example the URL for my file is:

```
http://discovery.[COMPANY].com/discovery/livelink/85587298/Book1.xlsx
```

My understanding is that I would have to use `LiveLinkDav` in my .Open statement. So the code I tried was:

```
Workbooks.open "http://discovery.[COMPANY].com/discovery/livelinkdav/[COMPANY]/[ID]/[DEPARTMENT]/[GROUP]/Book1.xlsx"
```

Excel brings up a status box like it is trying to open but the final result is a file called Book1 with a tab Book1 instead of the file on the server. I have tried a few versions of this with the same result. The drop down showing the folder structure is as follows:

```
Library
  [Company]
    [ID]
      [Department]
        [Group]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the LL server on your local network? If Yes then you may be able to use a UNC-format path such as (eg) `\\discovery.company.com\livelinkdav\[company]\[id]\[dept]\[group]\Book1.xlsx`

Comment: That is one of the ways I tried to structure my statement and it resulted in a blank Excel doc.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a not supported nor documented interface.
You could use SOAP/Webservices or starting in version 10.5 you can use the new ReST API.

What you could try is

http://discovery.company.com/discovery/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=84487298&objAction=download

Comment: That would mean that I would have to know the ObjID for every item before I try to have VBA open them. I am not sure that going out to the site and look up each ObjID would save me any time.